# What is the difference between `lightgrey` and `lightgray` in CSS?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, background-color

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 to edit my CSS. When I wanted to use a light gray color, the IntelliSense suggested me this:

[image]

Is there any difference?

Comment: Pretty easy to lookup yourself: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/

Comment: Other than a Hamming distance of `1`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [CSS3 Color](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color), there is no difference:

```
┌────────────┬─────────┬─────────────┐
│ Color name │ Hex rgb │   Decimal   │
├────────────┼─────────┼─────────────┤
│ lightgray  │ #d3d3d3 │ 211,211,211 │
│ lightgrey  │ #d3d3d3 │ 211,211,211 │
└────────────┴─────────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: Probably included just to cater to both US and UK spellings

Comment: @light Digging deeper - probably because both spellings were standard [X11 color names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names), which is where CSS got most of its named colors from.

Answer (score 10):

en-US:

```
.foo { color: gray; }
```

en-UK:

```
.foo { colour: grey; }
```

since `colour`is not supported, use `gray`

Answer (score 3):

They are exactly the same color , [check this article for more information.](http://blog.dictionary.com/gray-or-grey/)

> Gray is the more popular spelling in the US, while grey reigns supreme
>   in the UK.

Comment: The question is whether there's a *technical* difference, not what the words mean from a linguistic standpoint.

Comment: Did you read **They are exactly the same color** part of my answer ? @duskwuff

Comment: The article that you're linking is talking about the English language meaning of the words. While it's true in this case that they're also identical in this particular programming meaning, English language and computers don't always agree — consider "referer" vs. "referrer", for instance.

Answer (score 2):

I've found in IE7 that "lightgrey" maps to a light grey/gray color but "lightgray" maps to a darker grey/gray. So I'd recommend you use the rgb values to get the color you desire across older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

`lightgray` is not supported by IE ≤7; `lightgrey` is supported though.
That's the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Thats confusing I think its the IntelliSense dictionary problem in US dictionary its spelled as **LIGHTGRAY** and in UK dictionary its **LIGHTGREY**. But it should give same color value.